# How to resolve dependency by using a named registertype in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container, resolve

```
public interface IFoo {}

public interface IBar {}

public class Foo1 :  IFoo {}

public class FooOne : IFoo {}
public class FooTwo : IFoo {}

public class BarOne : IBar
{
    public BarOne(IFoo foo) {}        
} 

public class BarTwo : IBar
{
    public BarTwo(IFoo foo) {}        
} 

 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooOne>("One")
            .RegisterType<IFoo, FooTwo>("Two")
            .RegisterType<IBar, BarOne>("One")
            .RegisterType<IFoo, BarTwo>("Two");                

        string fooType = "One";
        string barType = "Two";

        IFoo myFoo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(fooType);
        IBar myBar = container.Resolve<IBar>(barType);
    }
}
```

Code sample above throws this error :

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "ConsoleApplication5.IBar", name = "Two". Exception occurred while:
>   while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current
>   type, ConsoleApplication5.IFoo, is an interface and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving ConsoleApplication5.BarTwo,Two (mapped from
>   ConsoleApplication5.IBar, Two)   Resolving parameter "foo" of
>   constructor ConsoleApplication5.BarTwo(ConsoleApplication5.IFoo foo)
>       Resolving ConsoleApplication5.IFoo,(none)

My solution is using `DependencyResolver` which changes this line:

```
IBar myBar = container.Resolve<IBar>(barType);
```

to this:

```
IBar myBar = container.Resolve<IBar>(barType, new DependencyOverride<IFoo>(myFoo));
```

I want to solve this issue using `RegisterType` method. Is it possible or is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Some details are missing. You need to register IMessageType with container somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Tilak I edit the post. The error message was belonging to the original code.  Now you can see the simplified version's error message.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine which of your IFoo **named** registrations unity should use when your resolving an IBar.

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooOne>("One")
         .RegisterType<IFoo, FooTwo>("Two")
         .RegisterType<IBar, BarOne>("One", new InjectionConstructor(
                                     new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("One")))
         .RegisterType<IBar, BarTwo>("Two", new InjectionConstructor(
                                     new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Two")));
```

The Problem is that IFoo is twice registered by different implementations and unity does not know which one it should use when resolving that type.

Comment: You are right but in this example it previously resolves IFoo with named registration "One". I want to force Unity to keep using same registration whenever it needs to resolve IFoo afterwards. Isn't that possible or am I missing some point?

Comment: IFoo "One" is resolved because it has no dependency in the constructor. so Unity has no Problem to resolve it. The Problem were your IBar registrations. I don't get what you mean by the "using the same Registration". In your example when you're resolving an IFoo by Name there is no problem, but the IBar is registered twice and has a dependecy on IFoo which is also registered twice. You have to tell Unity on the registration which of the registered IFoo it should use.

Comment: @Mehmet Kemal Bayer if you want to resolve always same `IFoo` why do you need then named registration?

Comment: @Lepijohnny because there are 4 possibilities FooOne-BarOne, FooOne-BarTwo, FooTwo-BarOne, FooTwo-BarTwo and decision of which couple is going to be used depends on an external data.

Comment: @Mehmet Kemal Bayer and these external data can be changed in runtime?

Comment: @Mehmet Kemal Bayer  in that case I would prefer to create some kind of factory which will resolve these interfaces depend on the input data instead of trying to solve that in Ioc. Then register that `IFactoryFooBar` into Ioc.

Comment: @Mehmet, as Lepijohny mentioned, you need Factory, because your IFoo (in IBar) depends on data.  If IFoo is fixed (like FooOne for Bar1, and FooTwo for BarTwo, then only you can leverage RegisterType. Or you can have BarOne, BarTwo, BarThree, BarFour, for all your scenarios, and pick based on need.

Comment: @Lepijohnny, this is where we were. We are trying to use named registration instead of factory but I understand it is not possible in our case. Thank you all.